# How to remove slowness of powerbuilder 12.6 application?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder.net, powerbuilder-2017

It's taking more than 15 minutes to search for Library entry.can anybody suggest how i can remove slowness of the application?

[Below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7F4v.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Big PBLs mean slow searches. Segregate your objects. Many people separate by object type. If you are in a hurry then this will work in a pinch. I work with huge applications. I organize PBLs by application function. This can also improve your compile time.

Back up your PBLs then optimize them. In the library painter (shift-F10) right click on the PBL and choose Optimize.

Our application has libraries that never change like the PowerBuilder Foundation Class PBLs. You can build runtime libraries (PBD) for them, then in your library list, change .PBL to .PBD. If you need to change an object in one of your "static" libraries, just change .PBD back to .PBL in your library list.

I export my objects to a folder and use my favorite text search tool. Windows search will also work on exported objects. I can search 7200 objects in less than 15 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Export all source file and search them by a modern text editor.
Like vscode or notepad++

Comment: It doesn't answer the question

Comment: The powerbuilder's built-in search function is poorly performing.There is nothing you can do about it.